# Unable to install Ganache

Tags: ganache, brownie

I am learning Solidity from this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M576WGiDBdQ

And there is a section about ganache cli and brownie. Brownie doesn't run scripts because I am unable to install ganache for a reason which I couldn't find out. I am using windows 10.

This is some of the error code

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\d\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ganache\node_modules\leveldown
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@14.17.3 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.9.6 found at "C:\Users\d\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS using VS2019 (16.11.31727.386) found at:
npm ERR! gyp info find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Users\d\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\d\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
```

Comment: Install the ganache app instead of ganache cli

Comment: How will brownie detect ganache then?

Comment: Im not sure about brownie. But you usually need only the url or the node

Answer (score 1):

You could have stated the command you ran.

Nevertheless,
run: `npm install -g ganache-cli`

To get list of other parameters: `ganache-cli --help`